# Can the Predicate<Object> for CollectionView.Filter be in a different class?

Tags: c#, wpf, collectionview

I have a TagTypeController class that provides a collection view to a controller for a WPF UserControl, which holds a private reference to the collection view.

```
_ttController = new TagTypeController(_isProd);
CollectionView tagTypeList = _ttController.getTagTypes();
```

In the TagTypeController, when creating the CollectionView, I'm setting the filter delegate

```
if (_tagTypeList == null)
    _tagTypeList = new CollectionView(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_tagTypeTable));
    _tagTypeList.Filter = new Predicate<object>(filterTagTypes);
```

I would like to locate all the logic for filtering, etc. of that collectionview in the TagTypeController class.  The problem is, when the text changes in the TextBox of the UserControl, I'm responding to that event by delegating to the controller for the UserControl.  When I ask the tagTypeList to refresh, it does not call the filterTagTypes method.  Is it not possible to have the filter delegate in a different class?

Thanks.

EDIT: adding requested code

```
//parse the string to get just the portion after the last comma and space
Int32 _lastComma = _tempText.LastIndexOf(",");
_ttController.searchText = _tempText.Substring(_lastComma + 1).Trim();

tagTypeList.Refresh();
```

Comment: Do you have a different controller for the textbox? Also can you post the code which refreshes tagTypeList. I think it would help clarify the question.

Comment: There two controllers.  One is for the UserControl, and therefore, by extension, the TextBox.  The other manages the data model for TagTypes, and that's the controller that is providing the CollectionView and the one doing the filtering.  I've edited to post the code for the refresh.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be that you are using the filter predicate rather than the event.  If you look at the [CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.filter.aspx) documentation it says:

> If your view object comes from a
>   CollectionViewSource object, you apply
>   filtering logic by setting an event
>   handler for the Filter event.

So instead of setting the property you want to use the event handler so the code would look like

```
_tagTypeList.Filter += FilterTagTypesHandler;
```

where `FilterTagTypesHandler` is defined like

```
private void FilterTagTypesHandler(object sender, FilterEventArgs e){
  //do filtering
}
```

The other possibility is that you are creating a new `CollectionView` instead of casting the result of `GetDefaultView()`.  You are probably losing your connection to the control when you do that.  If you look at the [CollectionViewSource's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview.aspx) the reccommend way of using it is

```
myCollectionView = (CollectionView)
    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(rootElem.DataContext);
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion originally (I read the same MSDN documentation), but I got operator += cannot be applied to operands of type System.Predicate<object> and method group.  I'm not sure why I wrote my code getting the CollectionView the way I did; I've always written it the way you suggested.  Writing it that way and using the predicate compiles but throws a NotSupportedException.

Comment: I've found a workaround, though I'd love to understand what's going on.  I've added all the rows from my DataTable into a generic List<>, and then taken the default view of the List<> to get my CollectionView.  The Predicate filtering now works.

Comment: @Shawn  The first way I suggested you need to not use a predicate but an event handler as the right hand side operator. I'm a little confused about your work around. Are you setting the source of the CollectionViewSource to the List<T> when it works but if you set it to a DataTable it doesn't work?

Comment: I tried the event handler approach and received the operator += cannot be applied to operands of System.Predicate<object> error from the compiler.  For the second part, yes, I'm creating an intermediate List<T> from the DataTable, and then setting the List<T> as the source of the CollectionViewSource.  It works with that approach, but does not work with the DataTable (since the DataTable as source doesn't support filtering as mentioned in the documentation).